# How can I import a Windows project to Ubuntu on Qt?

Tags: windows, qt, ubuntu, porting

I wrote an application using the Qt SDK on Windows. I now want to run that Application on Ubuntu making some minor modifications (e.g. changing the default directory when user clicks on save). Is there a way to do this, preferably through Qt Creator?

Thanks.

Comment: Why won't you try downloading and installing Qt Creator on Linux and open your Qt project?

Comment: I did that, but I get an error 
'Error while building project MyNotes (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'qmake''

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu package manager try installing qt-dev-tools and relaunch creator

Comment: I also ready have that installed. My Qt SDK's installed in my home directory.

Comment: Then check QtCreator settings. Choose proper SDK path and it should work

Comment: I was using an invalid Qt SDK Path. :( It's working now. Thanks Kamil! Could you please write than as the answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that Qt SDK paths are set and valid

Answer (score 0):

You can open your `.pro` project file with qtcreator on Ubuntu. Just make sure that you don't use any windows specific libraries

Comment: I'm not using any Windows specific libraries but I still can't run the application because of qmake. I'm not quite sure why. There's nothing on the .pro file that is windows-specific, either.

Comment: Can you please post output from `qmake project.pro` from command line.