# How do I load a Qt project from Linux in Windows

Tags: linux, windows, qt, porting

I think my question is the opposite of: [How can I import a Windows project to Ubuntu on Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064091/how-can-i-import-a-windows-project-to-ubuntu-on-qt)

My team has created a Qt project (*.creator, *.files, etc. files) that they use from Linux.  I'm running Windows, and have the Qt Creator for Windows installed.  I also have a drive (Z:) mapped to the Linux drive with the source and project files.

When they open the .creator file (as a project), all the files show up in their Qt Creator running on Linux.  When I open that file (as a project) in Qt Creator for Windows, I only see 4 files (*.creator, *.config, *.files, *.includes), and I don't see the source files.

The *.files file has lines that look like:

> /home/user/path/file.cpp

And my drive mapping does map this file as Z:/home/user/path/file.cpp (and I'm opening the *.creator file from Z:).

I only need to view and edit the files - I don't need to build in Windows.  Is there a way I can use the existing Linux project files to load the project in Windows?  If not, what changes do I need to make?

Thank you.

Comment: Qt project use a .pro file, I've never heard about a .creator file.

Comment: Neither is `*.files` a known file extension omho. :D Whenever doing a Qt project that will be developed on multiple systems I would advise to add specific procedures to handle the specific platfrom (for example `win32 { <stuff specific to Windows> }` unless the project is very simplistic. If the `pro` file really has lines that contain `/home/user/path/file.cpp` it means your team has ignored this very same rule. In general absolute paths should be avoided whenever possible because of such issues (among others). The problem might also come from the mapping of the drive.

Comment: I don't know who set up that project, but something is completely broken there. A qmake project consists of a set of `.pro` and `.pri` files. **None** of them should contain any absolute paths of source files! Fix that problem and everything will work. And the development strategy is also completely broken: instead of sharing a source folder, set up a git repository for your project, and work off that. Sharing what amounts to a working copy between developers is a surefire way to corrupt your source files. You will be very sorry you even thought of doing that.

Comment: You can access the git repo on the linux server via ssh - that won't require setting up anything besides the repository itself.

Answer (score 1):

Usually u open the *.pro file with Qt Creator and if your paths in the pro file are relative and not absolute to that pro file, every file should be loaded into your project view.

Comment: It obviously won't work in this case because of `/home/user/path/file.cpp` etc. which shows the presence of absolute paths and with Linux structure on top of that.

Comment: Well you can just search/replace your absolute path with a empty string inside your pro file and fix that. That is why I wrote that the paths should be relative to the pro file.
As you posted earlier, absolute paths should be avoided anyway, I agree.

Comment: In his case, the paths should have "Z:" concatenated in front, as he said his Linux's home path is prefixed with Z:: in Windows. But yeah, best practice is to avoid using absolute paths, as you cannot share your project if paths are not relative to the .pro file